# Don't want Navigation and Tabs to appear on initial ViewController

Tags: ios, swift

In Xcode 7.3.1 using Swift 2, my initial ViewController that acts as a login/signup page has both Navigation and Tabs that shouldn't be there.

They are appearing, because I have a logout Segue that redirects the user back to the login screen. I don't want the Navigation or Tabs to appear on this view ever, is there a setting to disable these in the Storyboard?

Here is my Storyboard:

[image: Storyboard screenshot]

Comment: how is your log out view controller linked to your initial view controller? Is it through a segue on the storyboard? or programmatically? can you show some code for the segue?

Comment: Also, most likely you shouldn't have a segue *to* your login screen from logout, but rather you should `unwind` *back* to your login screen

Comment: It's linked through the segue on the storyboard, so no code is involved. The bars will go away if I remove the segue, so it's clearly the culprit. If I switch the segue from "Show" to "Present Modally" the navigation/tab bars don't appear. It technically solved the problem, but feels hackish. I'll investigate the `unwind` command (I'm new to iOS development).

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question. I was using the Show Segue incorrectly, but it looks like an Unwind Segue would have worked. Instead I just added these three lines to my logout function to avoid segues altogether:

```
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Login")
    self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

I appreciate the help!